Cannot Access Service From Node other than where container is created in docker swarm
All,
I am learning docker swarm. I created three node swarm. when I do docker node ls all are active and available status.
I create one service of nginx.
docker service create \ --name <SERVICE-NAME> \ --publish published=<PUBLISHED-PORT>,target=<CONTAINER-PORT> \ IMAGE
however i can access nginx through only the node where nginx container is running not from other nodes. what coluld be the possible reason. According to docs i would be able to access nginx through all nodes with opened host port.
I have read all this docker swarm manual but not worked.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/

this typically happens when a firewall blocks communication between nodes.

I disabled fire wall in all nodes. but it does not work. I think there is issue with nic card checksum validation.

are you on vmware? it has issues. that you fix as per the reply below.

my nodes os are running on bare metal ESXi virtualization. using below cmd solves my  problem.

I don't understand the combination of words: bare metal ESXi virtualization, but good.

Basically, esxi is a hypervisor that can be run directly without a host operating system. You can find details about it in https://www.vmware.com/products/cloud-infrastructure/esxi-and-esx

ethtool -k ens160 tx-checksum-ip-generic off
above command in all three nodes solved that issue. It's wired.
